# AWS HTTPS dropping HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have an application that is running in PHP. I have a ELB classic load balancer in AWS routing HTTPS requests.

I am trying to get the referer URL (understanding this isn't always present) but when I first load the page I can see it appear but then it immediately disappears. I'm guessing this is because ELB is routing HTTPS to HTTP and the page immediately assumes the current domain is the referer. Buuut, I don't know if this is correct and if it is, how can I fix it?

I've Googled but it hasn't come up with any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

Check your headers. If you use the X-Forwarded-Proto header is should pass along the referring protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) with the request. Give that a shot, let us know.

One note, ALB's strip this header out by design to prevent forgery. A NLB doesn't perform header manipulation.